# creating a dynamic field and getting the value

Tags: javascript, dom, dynamic

i posted another question about this, but i think this one will be more concise.

i've dynamically created a text field with javascript.  i've checked to see that it's in the DOM by getting its value, but when trying to access it from another function i get a value of null for the input object.  is it actually possible to get the current value from a dynamically created text field?

inside one function:

```
comment_field = 'comment-HE382U3-2';
document.getElementById(comment_field).value = 'Write a comment...';
```

inside the other:

```
comment_field = 'comment-HE382U3-2';
if (document.getElementById(comment_field).value == 'Write a comment...')
    { document.getElementById(comment_field).value = '';}
```

is not happening because there is no [HTMLInputObject] found in the DOM.  Please help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it actually possible to get the current value from a dynamically created text field?

Yes. It is just like any other element. If it is in the DOM, it is accessed the same way.

Verify the value of the `comment_field` variable. You're making reference to different functions, so perhaps that variable is out of scope.

Comment: comment_field is established earlier in the code... not displayed here

Comment: Is either one working? Or just the second one isn't working? Does it work if you hardcode the string `"comment-HE382U3-2"`?

Comment: the first one document.getElementById(comment_field) shows up [object HTMLInputElement]... the second shows up null, even hard coded

Comment: @Lucas: There's not enough information in the question to tell what is wrong. As long as the element is in the DOM when the second code example is being called, it should behave the same as if it was there when the page loaded.

Comment: @Lucas: Sure, but could you please describe exactly what I need to do to recreate the issue? When I click inside a field that has `'Write a comment...'`, the text disappears. This would seem to be what you want.

Comment: @Lucas: One thing I see is that in your `ghost()` function, the `number` parameter is `undefined`. This means that the first `if()` statement code doesn't run. Because it doesn't run `comment_field` is `undefined`, and `getDocumentById` relies on `comment_field`.

Comment: ...as far as I can tell, `ghost()` is called from `comment()` which passes the `subject` variable to the `number` parameter in `ghost()`. The initial value of `subject` is the `current` variable, which starts off as `''`. These would be some variables to take a look at.

Comment: i figured it out... thanks for all your help... simple fix... the comment_field declaration was not incrementing